# Extern structure logic

Tags: c

How to extern structure in c language. So that I can use into another structure.

Comment: What's LPPoniter? Do you want a pointer to the "extern structure" in your `b`, or do you want an actual member of the "extern structure" in `b`?

Comment: Are we suppose to guess what b is?

Comment: Suppose a and b both are structures.

Comment: @Arman: I suggest you edit your question to say that A and B are both structures, and explain very clearly what you are trying to do.  If English is a problem, then provide details as best as you can, and then ask someone to help edit.

Comment: @Arman, you specified `c` language in your question. Use logic and don't tag it C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming b is another source file. You can so something like:

file: file.h

```
#ifndef _FILE_H_
#define _FILE_H_
 struct emp {
 char name[100];
 };
#endif
```

file: a.c

```
#include "file.h"    
extern struct emp e; // declare struct var as extern.

int main() {

        printf("Name = %s\n",e.name);

        return 0;
}
```

file: b.c

```
#include "file.h"    
struct emp e = {"stackoverflow"}; // struct var defined here.
```

On running:

```
$ gcc *.c && ./a.out
Name = stackoverflow
```

You question is very unclear and you are *not new* on SO.

Comment: First thanks a lot for your answer. And I accept I am not be able to clearly describe my question due to my poor English.

I have try your code but when I include file.h into two separate files compiler give me the error of multiple deceleration of structure emp.

Comment: You will need something like 

    #ifndef FILE_H
    #define FILE_H
    [contents of file.h]
    #endif

Around file.h

Comment: Have my last upvote for today, but you should take Richo's suggestion. @Richo, the term for that is an "include guard."

Comment: Wow, I just encountered a comment from me a year ago. Anyway, I'd further like to note that names beginning with an underscore are reserved for the implementation, so you should use `FILE_H` instead of `_FILE_H_`.

Answer (score 0):

Extern struct works as well as extern, at least when the extern is in the header file and the actual struct is in a cpp file that includes that header. I don't think "extern struct" is necessary so much as just "extern".